# Scroll a "position: fixed" div on a page but not above a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div ( a position:fixed) in the middle of the page. What I want is that when a user scrolls down the page the div moves down just like any div with a fixed position would do but when a user scrolls up, the div should not go above the upper div. That is, it stays where I created it.

Any idea how I would do that?

My current solution is below. The problem with this solution is that since I am hard coding the `top` position, the div bhevaes differently in different screens and that's a big issue.

### CSS

```
.div-fixed-position {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
     position: fixed; 
        right: 0;
        top: 625px; /* the problem! */
        z-index: 1000;

    width: 100%;

}
```

Many thanks

Comment: You would have to use a JS library like Waypoints http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/ to detect when a user scrolls past a certain point and enable/disable fixed positioning based on scroll position

Comment: Waypoints seems not to be working for some reason. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I use this JS to auto detect my `top` CSS attribute:-

### JS

```
var navHeight    = $('header.myheader').height();
var totalHeight = parseInt(headerHeight) + parseInt(navHeight) + 50;
$(".div-fixed-position").css({ top: totalHeight });
```

and I removed the top from my CSS.

### CSS

```
.div-fixed-position {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
     position: fixed; 
        right: 0;

        z-index: 1000;

    width: 100%;

}
```